# re.match no funciona como debería, no coincide en el medio del texto

Tags: python, python-2.7, regex

Tengo una expresión regular muy simple `5( |$)` que no funciona en un caso según he podido observar.

Estoy usando la librería `re` de Python, y compilo la expresión como `exp = re.complie(r"5( |$)")`.

Si uso `exp.match("5")` devuelve `True` como debería, pero en cambio `exp.match("bla bla 5")` devuelve `False`.

¿Es un problema de mi expresión o es porque necesito usar algún "flag"?

Comment: ¿Podría agregar que es lo que desea hacer y anexar su código?

Comment: Mi intención es comprobar si hay un 5 o un número que acabe en 5 en cualquier string que recibo, el código se resume en `if exp.match(string): do_something`. @Reynald0

Comment: Porque simplemente no verificas si existe un 5 en el string? `if "5" in vString`?

Comment: Porque de esa manera no verifico que 5 es la última cifra @Einer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es un tema con la expresión regular, sino con el método que estás utilizando.

[match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) comprueba si coincide ***desde el inicio del string***.

Deberías usar [seach()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search), [findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) o 
[finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer).

```
import re

exp = re.compile(r"5( |$)")
resultado = exp.search("bla bla 5")
```